# liftweb S.error redirects to previous page

Tags: lift

I'm currently working with lift and I recently faced a difficult with redirects.

When I try to show an error or notice with `S.error`, it redirects to the page which I was previously. And I couldn't find a work around for that. I assume it's a default behavior of lift and there should be a work around. Please post how to changed this behavior.

Answer (score 2):

It's unlikely that S.error is causing the redirect.

I presume you're calling S.error while processing a form submission. If so, you need to call S.redirectTo or S.seeOther after your processing is complete to redirect the browser to a different page. If you don't Lift's default behaviour is to reload the form on which you have just clicked submit.